# Using variable in SELECT and output result like a normal SELECT

Tags: oracle, variables, select, plsql

I have a `SELECT` which is quite slow and I think it'll be fast when using two `SELECT` instead of a subselect or join.

Basically I need to select some numbers from a table and use them in the where-statement of another `SELECT`.

At the moment I have working:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_skus VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(num,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY num) INTO v_skus FROM VIEWNAME WHERE parent IN ('1000');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_skus=' || v_skus);
END;
```

That would give me a '`1001,1002`' in the variable.

I want to use this now in another SELECT like

```sql
... WHERE number IN (v_skus)
```

If I put the second `SELECT` in the `BEGIN` block I get the error "INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement".

So do I have to use another variable for the actual result, and how do I manage to get the actual tablelike result like a plain `SELECT` would do?

Is my approach wrong?

Comment: I am pretty sure that two statements won't make this faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm afraid that you're right ... :-(

Comment: Please post the SQL you say is slow, perhaps we can work with that. BTW: 2 selects is a virtual guarantee to make the overall process slower. DBMS have been in the business of optimizing joins for 50 years. You use 2 queries then you are taking over the join, you don't use the JOIN operation, but that's still what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using 2 different selects when you can use single nested select -

```
DECLARE
  v_skus VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  SELECT YOUR_FIRST_QUERY
  INTO v_skus
  FROM YOUR_OTHER_TABLE
  WHERE WHERE number IN (SELECT num FROM VIEWNAME WHERE parent IN ('1000'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_skus=' || v_skus);
END;
```

Comment: i used a subselect before and it had the same performance issues + i've read, that oracle does internally a left join when you use a subselect. So using the subselect wont change anything.